# find all triplets of positive rationals satisfying this property

Tags: polynomials, rational-numbers

Find all $(x, y, z) \in Q^{+} | (a, b, c) \in Z^{+} $ for $ a = x + y + z, b = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}, c = xyz$.

I have tried using Viete's formulas, setting $x, y, z$ as the roots of some polynomial $p(t) = a_3t^3 + a_2t^2 + a_1t^2 + a_0 = a_3(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$, but made little progress... one idea I had was to, since $(x, y, z) \in Q^{+}$, using the rational roots theorem (assuming that we can write p(t) with integer coefficients):

Let $x = \frac{s_1}{t_1}, y = \frac{s_2}{t_2}, z = \frac{s_3}{t_3}$ where $(s_1, s_2, s_3, t_1, t_2, t_3) \in Z$. This gives that $s | a_0 \ \forall s \in \{s_1, s_2, s_3\}$ and $t | a_3 \ \forall t \in \{t_1, t_2, t_3\}$. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Note that $bc = yz+xz+xy$ is an integer, so you can then use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) with $p(t) = (t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$ and the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: @JohnOmielan, yeah, that's what i thought... i wrote up some equations relating the coefficients with their respective combinations with a, b, c but couldn't really get anywhere...

Comment: I've expanded on my comment with an answer. I trust it'll help you to see how you can get past where you were ran into trouble with your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You've made good progress. To finish, first use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) or just expand to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
p(t) & = (t-x)(t-y)(t-z) \\
& = t^3 - (x+y+z)t^2 + (yz+xz+xy)t - xyz
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note $bc = yz+xz+xy$ is an integer. Thus, all of the coefficients in \eqref{eq1A} are integers, with the coefficient of $t^3$ (i.e., $1$) and $xyz$ being non-zero, so the [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) states all of the rational roots of \eqref{eq1A} are of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ where $q$ is a factor of the coefficient of $t^3$, i.e., $1$, so $q=1$. Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are all positive integers.

This automatically means that $a$ and $c$ are integers, so they don't impose any constraints. For dealing with $b$, due to symmetry, WLOG consider $x \le y \le z$.

With $x = 1$, we can have $y = 1$, which means that $z = 1$. If $y = 2$, then $b = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{z}$, so if $z \ge 3$, this is not an integer, which means $z = 2$. Finally, if $y \ge 3$, then we have $\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z} \le \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$, so $b$ can't be an integer.

With $x = 2$, if $y = 2$, then $\frac{1}{z}$ must be an integer, which is not possible since $z \ge 2$. If $y = 3$, then $z = 6$ is required. Next, if $y = 4$, then only $z = 4$ works. Finally, if $y \ge 5$, then $b \le \frac{1}{2} + 2\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) = \frac{9}{10}$, which is not permitted.

With $x = 3$, only $y = z = 3$ allows $b$ to be an integer (i.e., $1$ in this case).

Finally, $x \ge 4$ means that $b \le 3\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$, which is not allowed.

Thus, the $(x,y,z)$ are, in some order of vales, the elements of $\{(1,1,1),(1,2,2),(2,3,6),(2,4,4),(3,3,3)\}$.

Comment: really nice solution! just one question: how do you know that the leading coefficient of p(t) is 1?

Comment: @MartinWestin Thank you for the compliment. However, I'm not clear on what you're asking. The largest non-zero term, in terms of powers of $t$, of $p(t)$ in $(1)$ is $t^3$. There's an implicit coefficient of $1$ since $(1)t^3 = t^3$. Note I could've instead used $q(t) = d(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$ for any non-zero integer $d$, so with $d \neq 1$, the leading term's coefficient would then not be $1$. However, the roots are still the same. Also, all of the coefficients would still be integers, but it would then obscure trying to use the Rational root theorem to show all of the roots are integers. ...

Comment: @MartinWestin (cont.) If this doesn't resolve your issue, please explain it further.